# How to get the current page in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I get the  current page url?

**Purpose: Log in via Gmail client**

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, slowMo:50});
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://my.gumtree.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

 //click on Google Sign In button
const myButton = await page.$('#google-sign-in-button');
myButton.click();

  //wait for the pop up window to load
const nav1 = new Promise(res => browser.on('targetcreated', res))
await nav1

const pages = await browser.pages();
const secondPage = pages[2];
await secondPage.focus('input[type=email]')
await secondPage.keyboard.type('someValidEmail@gmail.com')


customButton = await secondPage.$('span.VfPpkd-vQzf8d');
customButton.click()

 //Everything works as expected  until here
await page.waitForNavigation()
```

** How can I get the current page url? Should be at index 3 **

```
const allPages = await browser.pages();



// console.log("0 " + allPages[0].url());
// console.log("1 " + allPages[1].url());
// console.log("2 " + allPages[2].url());
// console.log("3 " + allPages[3].url()); //prints undefined, this should be the top page

  prints: 
0 about:blank
1 https://my.gumtree.com/login
2 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/identifier?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%2Fmy.gumtree.com%3Fid%3Dauth500948&response_type=permission%20id_token&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm&client_id=67555700125-lvoarr4qau5lkhuks3bn3bl9u3bmmfuf.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.gumtree.com&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

the message is Cannot read property 'url' of undefined





//await browser.close();
})().catch((error) =>{
  console.error(error.message)
});


app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('server started');
})
```

Comment: allPages[2] is the 3rd page. allPages[3] would be the fourth page if there were one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a built in function for that.
You anyway can find a solution on this closed puppeteer github issue
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/443#issuecomment-423440720

```
   async function getActivePage(browser, timeout) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while(new Date().getTime() - start < timeout) {
            var pages = await browser.pages();
            var arr = [];
            for (const p of pages) {
                if(await p.evaluate(() => { return document.visibilityState == 'visible' })) {
                    arr.push(p);
                }
            }
            if(arr.length == 1) return arr[0];
        }
        throw "Unable to get active page";
    }
```

Comment: Why do I need ```await``` in this case ```if(await p.evaluate(()``` ? Isn't ```p``` already loaded, why is it considered asynchronous?

Comment: You are right. P is resolved already. Anyway, Evaluate executes JS in the pages context and is an promise which we need to await.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that the ```p.evaluate()``` refers to this function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: The problem I am facing now is that after logging in, the current page is no longer pushed to the ```arr```. Now the page shown in the browser  is ```https://my.gumtree.com/manage/ads```. Unfortunately, it's not showing anymore in the console. Any idea how to go about it?